# matplotlib pyqt5 backend issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pyqt

I was try to embed matplotlib into pyqt5, my environment is window7 with python3.4, matplotlib 1.5 (matplotlib-1.5.0rc2.win-amd64-py3.4.exe).

I found a example show it work on http://www.boxcontrol.net/embedding-matplotlib-plot-on-pyqt5-gui.html#.Vh9eBd-qqkp and the environment is almost the same as mine, except the matplotlib is Matplotlib 1.4.2

however when I import backend_qt5agg, exception was raising:

> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 15, in 
>       from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 27, in 
>       import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\figureoptions.py", line 17, in 
>       import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\formlayout.py", line 58, in 
>       from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 144, in 
>       raise RuntimeError("PyQt{4,5} bindings found despite sip importing\n"
>       RuntimeError: PyQt{4,5} bindings found despite sip importing
>   Please install PyQt4 or PyQt5, uninstall sip or explicitly set the pyside backend.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg", force=True)

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
```

I am seperately using Pyqt5 and matplotlib in my other project, and both work.
Could you tell me how to fix it?

**Update** after I uninstall matplotlib matplotlib-1.5.0, and install 1.4.2 instead, the above imports don't throw exception. Would that be a bug of 1.5.2